# File Drag & Drop ability in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, plugins, drag-and-drop

I was wondering if any one knew of a plug-in or a way to:

I would like to be able to drag files from Solution Explorer to a Windows Explorer window and have the file copied to the location in Explorer.

Currently using VS2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [VS Explorer](http://www.ssware.com/vsexplorer/vsexplorer.htm) - an addin which adds a file and folder browsing window to Visual Studio. It allows you to drag-drop files from Solution Explorer to external folders, vice versa and more.